# Events with overlay div on top of iframe

Tags: javascript, html

i have a div that is overlays an iframe.  I am using the div as a handle for the user to drag the iframe around with.  The iframe may contain cross domain content, so i cant get rid of it.

If a user clicks on text underneath the div it highlights the text in IE9.  This is preventing my onmousedown event from firing.  If i click anywhere else on the div that does not have iframe text underneath it, the event is fired, and everything works as it should.  Is there a way to get around this?

both FF and Chrome behave as expected, without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem in IE9 you can try the following workaround: add a background-color (e.g. #fff) to the div that overlaps the iframe and set the opacity of the div to 0 (opacity is only supported by IE9, not IE8). I have setup a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Yru3/4/) to demonstrate this solution. Note that the overlapping div is clickable and not the iframe contents (links and text).